# How to include header in order?

Tags: c++, opengl, include, glew

I have a OpenGL project with many header files. I use the GLEW lib and my `Main.cpp` starts like this:

```
// use GLEW as static lib requires GLEW_STATIC
#define GLEW_STATIC 
#include <GL/glew.h>
// ...
```

There reported an error:

```
GL/glew.h(85): fatal error C1189: #error:  gl.h included before glew.h
```

So I need to include `GL/glew.h` before any other header which include `gl.h`. So I add these lines in each header:

```
#ifndef GLEW_INCLUDED
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#define GLEW_INCLUDED
#endif
```

I have to modify every header, seems like a "dirty" work. Is there any clean way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clean way to do it is to exercise self-control. Or more to the point, stop including `gl.h`. If you're using an [OpenGL loading library](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library), then it controls your access to OpenGL. Let it do its job and only include its headers.

So there's no need for `GLEW_INCLUDED`.

As for `GLEW_STATIC`, that's a define you add to your build system on the command line, not to every file that you use. Much like you don't define `NDEBUG` or other similar defines.

Comment: I recovered the headers by removing those lines. I found that some headers include `glew.h` and none of them includes `gl.h`. Then I added `#define GLEW_STATIC` `#include <GL\glew.h>` to `Main.cpp`. Still got the error. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @stanleyerror: I said to put `GLEW_STATIC` into your build system on the command line, not to `main`. If you're using a makefile, then you add it to your compiler's command line switches. If you're using Visual Studio, then there's a setting for defines in your project (both debug and release). I can't tell you how to use your build tools, but that's where you put it.